# powershell type command causing invalid characters

Tags: powershell, shell, npm, serialization, cmd

as a simple example i have two Javascript files.

toAppend.js:

```
console.log("appended content");
```

main.js

```
console.log("main content");
```

when i run:

```
type toAppend.js >> main.js
```

in my power shell, it copies over a bunch of invalid chars, in between each letter. see image.
[image: invalid chars]

second, when i try to add this command to an NPM script, it says i have the incorrect syntax.

Any idea why this issue is occuring?
since i'm using windows, i suppose the shell used to execute npm would be cmd.exe

Comment: The file redirection operators in PowerShell (`>` and `>>`) always use UTF16 encoding. Try `type toAppend.js |Add-Content main.js` instead

Comment: @Mathis is correct, but just to clarify: UTF-16LE is used in _Windows PowerShell_, whereas BOM-less UTF-8 is used in PowerShell [Core] v6+ - in neither case is the target file's existing character encoding considered. See the  "Inconsistent default encoding behavior in Windows PowerShell" section of the linked answer. As an aside: `type` is a built-in alias for the [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) cmdlet, and `>>` is _in effect_ the same as `... | Out-File -Append`